# Не рабoтает скрипт jQuery

Tags: jquery

Проект делаю в WebStorm. В нем два скрипта. Один работает (плавная прокрутка якоря), другой нет (выезжающее меню слева).

Если скопировать все в codepen и подключить в нем jQuery 3.3.1, тогда все работает.

Заранее сорри, если что не так скинул или написал, я совсем новичок в этом :)

https://codepen.io/t_baag/pen/MRePEW

```
$('.menu_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#first_Something_Nothing").on("click","a", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id  = $(this).attr('href'),
            top = $(id).offset().top;
        $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: top}, 1800);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.menu_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
  });
});
```